# Remote Desktop Services Remote Audio Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services, thin-client, remote-desktop-services

I have a server running server std 2008 r2 fully patched.  There are 8 Wyse C10LE's that connect to the server via RDS.  Everything is working fantastically with the exception that there is no audio... There is not a sound card in the server, but I have the setting to bring the audio to the wyse terminals.  I have made sure that the group policy has been configured so that the audio should be working on the clients end.  Do I need a sound card, if not has anyone else ran into similar issues?

Comment: It's been a very long time but I thought we did need sound cards on the servers to process the sent audio. Someone else will have to verify that it's still the case (or that I'm imagining things)

Comment: Do we need to look at a heavy duty audio card or just a plain jane audio card?  Do you or someone have any recommendations?  Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Any sound card will work. The key is in running a sound driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Audio Service running on the server? Check the tray icon and Task Manager Services tab.
[image]

Comment: JimB, under the reg entry you gave me I do not have any items listed, should I go ahead and add this item in?

Comment: JimB, I went ahead and added the AllowRemoteSound to the registry with a value of 1

Comment: Sometimes the Windows Audio related services need a restart from the Services management window in case they were running but sound was not working.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the windows audio service is running.  Windows cannot redirect the audio without it. 2008 does not require an audio card (2003 DOES)

Comment: All services are running that should be running and to my knowledge is configured properly.  However I do have the speaker with the red 'X' over it in the system tray.  I also do not have an audio card.

Comment: what does what does "AllowRemoteSound" under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server" say?

Comment: the red X on the speaker usually means the audio service is not running

Comment: in my screenshot below the red X is on the speaker even though the service is running.

Comment: @tombull89 - it can also mean it's muted

Answer (score 0):

The Red X means that no audio device is installed, which as Jim B pointed out is not required. When connecting to the server, if all the settings are in place you should see the Volume icon active (no RED X) and hovering over it you should see "Remote Playback Microsoft RDP Audio Transport".

Double check the Audio redirection settings on the RDP protocol on the server, on the user object in AD, and on the client.